# Drop-down list selection does not display in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the displayround div to display what is selected in the selection box. Somehow when I removed some of the array values it stopped working.. Any idea why?

**HTML**:

```
<div id="buttonholder">
<button id="previous">< Previous round</button>
<button id="next">Next round ></button>
<button id="current">> Current round <</button>
<div style="font-size: 0;">
<form id="inputform">

<select name="rounds" id="selectbox">
    <option value="2013/2014">--- 2013/2014 ---</options>
    <option value="2012/2013">--- 2012/2013 ---</options>
    <option value="2011/2012">--- 2011/2012 ---</options>
    <option value="2010/2011">--- 2010/2011 ---</options>
    <option value="2009/2010">--- 2009/2010 ---</options>
    <option value="2008/2009">--- 2008/2009 ---</options>
    <option value="2007/2008">--- 2007/2008 ---</options>
    <option value="2006/2007">--- 2006/2007 ---</options>

</select>

</form>
</div>
<div id="displayround">

</div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    var season = new Array();
    season[0]="2013/2014";
    season[1]="2012/2013";
    season[2]="2011/2012";
    season[3]="2010/2011";
    season[4]="2009/2010";
    season[5]="2008/2009";
    season[6]="2007/2008";
    season[7]="2006/2007";
    season[8]="2005/2006";

    $("#buttonholder").find("button").addClass("left")
    $("#buttonholder").find("#submit").removeClass("left").addClass("right")
    $("#buttonholder").find("#inputform").addClass("right");

    $("#displayround").text(season[0]).data('index', 0);

    $("#next").click(function () {
        var index = +$("#displayround").data('index') + 1;
        if (index >= season.length) index = 0;
        $("#displayround").text(season[index]).data('index', index);
    });

    $("#previous").click(function () {
        var index = +$("#displayround").data('index') - 1;
        if (index <= -1) index = season.length - 1;
        $("#displayround").text(season[index]).data('index', index);
    })
```

The problem is somewhere in this function I'm assuming:

```
    $("#selectbox").change(function() {
        var index = $(this).val().match(/\d+/) - 1;
        $("#displayround").text(season[index]).data('index', index);
    });

}); //end of document.ready function
```

Comment: You again :), Let me tell you problem. now selected value be something like `2013/2014`, so `"2013/2014".match(/\d+/)` will return `["2013"]` an array. Even if you convert your data let say `2013`. You don't have  array of that length

Comment: Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddler.net) please :D

Comment: This looks strange: `var index = +$("#displayround").data('index') + 1;` What's the `+` doing there?

Comment: @CornéM, `+"1"` will convert string to number

Comment: I created a fiddle for you: [http://jsfiddle.net/uN77u/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/uN77u/1/)

Comment: @Do you never sleep? :P So you're saying I need to change val()?

Comment: @CornéM '+' before a string convert it to number if string is valid numeric value

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/uN77u/2/. And yes I do sleep. It seems I am getting addicted to SO

Comment: @Satpal so what exactly do I have to change to make it work properly?

Comment: As I have told you yesterday. store array index which you want to display as value.

Comment: @Satpal as I'm a noob at jquery I'm not quite sure how to do that

Comment: See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uN77u/2/) I have already done it for you

Comment: @Satpal Ah never mind now I saw the problem. Thanks.